# Laravel 5.4: how to delete a file stored in storage/app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to delete a file that is stored in storage/app/myfolder/file.jpg. I have tried the following codes but none of this works:

```
use File    
$file_path = url().'/storage/app/jobseekers_cvs/'.$filename;
unlink($file_path);
```

and

```
use File
$file_path = public_path().'/storage/app/myfolder/'.$filename;
unlink($file_path);
```

and

```
use File
$file_path = app_path().'/storage/app/myfolder/'.$filename;
unlink($file_path);
```

and also,

```
File::Delete('/storage/app/myfolder/'.$filename);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 62):

You could either user Laravels facade `Storage` like this:

```
Storage::delete($file);
```

or you could use this:

```
unlink(storage_path('app/folder/'.$file));
```

If you want to delete a directory you could use this:

```
rmdir(storage_path('app/folder/'.$folder);
```

One important part to mention is that you should first check wether the file or directory exists or not.

So if you want to delete a file you should probably do this:

```
if(is_file($file))
{
    // 1. possibility
    Storage::delete($file);
    // 2. possibility
    unlink(storage_path('app/folder/'.$file));
}
else
{
    echo "File does not exist";
}
```

And if you want to check wether it is a directory do this:

```
if(is_dir($file))
{
    // 1. possibility
    Storage::delete($folder);
    // 2. possibility
    unlink(storage_path('app/folder/'.$folder));
    // 3. possibility
    rmdir(storage_path('app/folder/'.$folder));
}
else
{
    echo "Directory does not exist";
}
```

Answer (score 23):

Use [storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#deleting-files)

```
//demo 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::delete($filename);
```

Another way,

```
unlink(storage_path('app/folder/'.$filename));
```

Comment: how can I set the path. like storage/app/myfolder/filename

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer. This code worked for me.

```
unlink(storage_path('app/foldername/'.$filename));
```

Comment: It worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 6):

The delete method accepts a single filename or an array of files to remove from the disk:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::delete('file.jpg');

Storage::delete(['file.jpg', 'file2.jpg']);
```

If necessary, you may specify the disk that the file should be deleted from:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::disk('s3')->delete('folder_path/file_name.jpg');
```

**Delete A Directory**

Finally, the deleteDirectory method may be used to remove a directory and all of its files:

```
Storage::deleteDirectory($directory);
```

Answer (score 3):

This code worked for me.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
....
$storagePath  = Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();
if(file_exists($storagePath.$file)) unlink($storagePath.$file);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
Storage::delete("public/team/" . $mem->avatar);
```

Use code above but you need to specify the full path to your file.

Answer (score 2):

The default root for the Storage facade is configured in config/filesystems.php and the default is:

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],
```

So you should use:

```
Storage::delete('myfolder/'.$filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
unlink(public_path('uploads\users'). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$user->image);
```

This worked for me..

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Where does `$user` come from? The OP did not use that variable

Answer (score 0):

For example update customer profile image and remove old image

Stored file in database ($customer->image)

```
/storage/customers/mhPKW870zGFupAZLI5cwNLoHTAuguCQWoBrDXJCU.jpeg
```

Update method

```
if ($request->file('image')) {
  if ($customer->image) {
      // get filename
      $filename = str_replace('/storage/customers/', '', $customer->image);
      // remove old image
      unlink(storage_path('app/public/customers/'.$filename));
  }
  // add new image
  $path = Storage::putFile('public/customers', $request->file('image'));
  $url = Storage::url($path);

  $customer->image = $url;
}
       
$saveResult = $customer->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

For local storage use this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::disk('local')->delete('folder_path/file_name.jpg');
```

For S3 bucket use this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::disk('s3')->delete('folder_path/file_name.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: path my file]

for example, I store my file ini that path, so I use this code for delete 020521_0204_17111623001_8340.pdf

```
Storage::delete('files/8340/020521_0204_17111623001_8340.pdf');
```

Because by default in config/filesystems.php, default path is storage_path('app/public').

Answer (score 0):

```
 Storage::disk('s3')
        ->delete("path/to/file/".$fileName.".mp3");
```

Remember to include the file extension if you are working with s3 objects. I forgot in my case but seems to be equally important. Hope this helps.