# Can not delete a file stored in storage

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-7

stuck in deleting the file I am saving into storage directory. My confs as shown below.

config/filesystems

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

this is how I am saving the image.

```
if ($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        Storage::disk('public')->put("/uploads/".$image->hashName(),  File::get($image));
        $input['image'] = 'uploads/' . $image->hashName();
    }
```

I am using Laravel 7 and the image is being successfully uploaded, can anyone please suggest me the best way to remove the files stored in there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.4: how to delete a file stored in storage/app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45065039/laravel-5-4-how-to-delete-a-file-stored-in-storage-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like Laravel to automatically manage streaming a given file to your storage location, you may use the `putFile` or `putFileAs` method. This method accepts either a `Illuminate\Http\File` or `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` instance and will automatically stream the file to your desired location:

```
use Illuminate\Http\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

// Automatically generate a unique ID for file name...
Storage::putFile('photos', new File('/path/to/photo'));

// Manually specify a file name...
Storage::putFileAs('photos', new File('/path/to/photo'), 'photo.jpg');
```

There are a few important things to note about the `putFile` method. Note that we only specified a directory name, not a file name. By default, the `putFile` method will generate a unique ID to serve as the file name. So in your case you don't need to use `$image->hasName()`.

`putFile()` also returns the path where the file was saved. So...

```
$path = Storage::putFile('photos', new File('/path/to/photo'));
//To delete it
Storage::delete($path);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store image with:

```
if(request('image'))
{
     $table_column_name = request('image')->hashName();
     request('image')->store('public/uploads/');
}
```

You can delete image with:

```
$data = MODAL_NAME::findOrFail($id);
Storage::delete('public/uploads/'.$data->image);
```